# Replace object reference in function

Tags: python

```py
def modify(a_dict):
    alt_dict = a_dict.copy()
    alt_dict['s'] = 2
    a_dict = alt_dict

a_dictionary = {}
a_dictionary['f'] = 5

modify(a_dictionary)
print(a_dictionary)
```

The expected result is that a_dictionary will now also containt the key 's'. I know lists and dictionaries are passed by reference as mutables, but is there a way to update the reference within a function as I'm trying to do above?.. Or is there a better way?..

To clarify, I do indeed need to make a copy, because the changes I make in inside my actual function in code I might discard if an exception happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a new object to the local variable doesn't help you here. But as dictionaries are mutable, you can clear and update the original dictionary given the new data:

```
def modify(a_dict):
    alt_dict = a_dict.copy()
    alt_dict['s'] = 2
    a_dict.clear()
    a_dict.update(alt_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
def modify(a_dict):
    alt_dict = a_dict.copy()
    alt_dict['s'] = 2
    # do lots of stuff

    # make sure all changes are "backported"
    a_dict.update(alt_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about returning the modified copy?

```
def modify(a_dict):
    alt_dict = a_dict.copy()
    alt_dict['s'] = 2
    return alt_dict

a_dictionary = {}
a_dictionary['f'] = 5

a_dictionary = modify(a_dictionary)
print(a_dictionary)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm returning other things in my actual code, that's why I needed to do it by reference, but this is a good suggestion

Comment: @JackAvante A function in Python can return an arbitrary number of objects.